# How to configure UglifyJS with Gradle?

Tags: build.gradle

Are there any ready-to-use Gradle plugins to use for UglifyJs? We are trying to configure Uglify something similar to what has been done [here](https://github.com/dennisaj/airlock/blob/master/build.gradle), but the owner of that project seems to have his own private artifactory to which he points to, thereby getting access to UglifyAntTask, which is a github-hosted project not following Gradle/Maven etc. (basically non-managed) JAR. We tried downloading this JAR to our project and tried configuring using the options suggested in gradle page as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') (or)
    compile files('uglifyjs-java-v1.0.jar')
}
```

Note: The (or) is not there in actual code, I mentioned only to indicate that we tried both options but it was not picking the JAR.

So at a later step, when we gave

```
ant.taskdef(name: "uglify", classname: "uglify.ant.UglifyTask", classpath: configurations.uglifyjs.asPath)
```

Gradle throws the following errror:

> taskdef class uglify.ant.UglifyTask cannot be found
>      using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

I am hoping that at least some one must have had the need to include non-managed 3rd party JAR and have figured out how to do this, if so, please point the solution/mistake we have made.

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the offical Gradle documentation describe it:

```
configurations {
  uglifyjs
}
dependencies {
  uglifyjs files('uglifyjs-java-v1.0.jar')
}
task uglifyjs << {
  ant.taskdef(name: 'uglifyjs', classname: 'uglify.ant.UglifyTask', classpath: configurations.uglifyjs.asPath)
  ant.uglifyjs( ... UglifyJS Ant Task parameters ... )
}
```

See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html#N11416

HTH