# how to uglify javascript files and css files using gradle task

Tags: javascript, gradle, uglifyjs

i am using gradle for spring mvc project. i have lots of javascript and css files. Using grunt i know how to uglify and minify them but with gradle i could only find minify and GZip.

```
 "com.eriwen.gradle.js".

gzipJs {
   source = minifyjs
   dest = file("${buildDir}/all-min.js")
}

minifyJs {
   source = combineJs
   dest = file("${buildDir}/all-min.js")
   sourceMap = file("${buildDir}/all.sourcemap.json")
   closure {
     warningLevel = 'QUIET'
   }
}
```

Only this two i could see for making files smaller. Or there is any other way of producing the same effects as uglify does.

Comment: What kind of "uglify" effects are you talking about?

Comment: As far as i can see your plugin is able to concat and minify your code. The minify task is using the Google Closure Compiler which parses your JavaScript, analyzes it, removes dead code and rewrites and minimizes what's left.

Comment: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/. this also reduces the size of file by replacing the variables and much more. it also makes your js files unreadable.

Comment: Same as GCC. So what is your problem here?

Comment: unglifyjs is seems to be only available through grunt. i want to use gradle task instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213312/how-to-configure-uglifyjs-with-gradle